# Changing who the email is from with WIN32OLE

Tags: ruby, email, outlook, win32ole

Is there a way to change who an email is from using `win32ole`?

```
outlook = WIN32OLE.new('Outlook.Application')
message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
message.Subject = 'Test email'
message.Body = 'This is the test body'
message.To = 'test@test.test'
message.From = ''me@me.me' #<= This doesn't work
message.Save
message.Send
```

When you run `message.From` you get the following error:

```
WIN32OLERuntimeError: unknown property or method: `From'
    HRESULT error code:0x80020006
      Unknown name.
```

So is there a way I can choose who the message is sent from?

Answer (score 1):

When sending through Exchange, use `SentOnBehalfOfName` property. It should contain the name of another Exchange user on who's behalf the current user can send. You of course need to have the right to send on behalf of that user.

When sending through SMTP, set the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property instead. It must be set to one of the `Account` objects retrieved from the `Namespace.Accounts` collection.

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: Example of what? Is it an Exchange or an SMTP account?

Comment: Exchange, sorry for the confusion

Comment: The property name is SentOnBehalfOfName, not SentOnBehalfOf.

Comment: It is Sent with a "t", not "d". Please take a look at an existing item with OutlookSpy - click the Item button to see all available properties.

Comment: That didn't work either.. You know I'm using Ruby right?

Comment: What was the exact problem? Run-time error? Compile error? The code ran but nothing happened? You need to be a lot more specific than that.